# Ramadan and smoking

Tags: ramadan, smoking

I know that drinking alcohol before Ramadan invalidates your fast. However, smoking isn’t the same I’ve found out?

Does smoking before Ramadan, but not during invalidate the fast?

Ps - I mean nicotine, not weed etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does one need to not consume any alcohol or drugs at least 30 days prior to the 1st day of Ramadan?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/988/does-one-need-to-not-consume-any-alcohol-or-drugs-at-least-30-days-prior-to-the)

Comment: I’ve already heard about this. And of course I know one shouldn’t be doing this at all but, I was wondering if there are any sources stating one shouldn’t smoke before Ramadan. 
Thank you!!

Comment: What you didn't note is that your statement "drinking alcohol before ramadan invalidates your fast" isn't true. The point of the linked question and its answers is that no matter which sin you do your obligation of fast and prayer remains, but you won't get any rewards (hasanat) for doing it,

Answer (score 1):

According to Islamic teachings, smoking during the month of Ramadan is considered a violation of the fast. Smoking is seen as an act that involves inhaling smoke and introducing it into the body, which breaks the fast. However, smoking before Ramadan, but not during the fasting hours, does not invalidate the fast, as long as the person does not consume anything during the fasting hours.

The purpose of fasting during Ramadan is to abstain from food, drink, and other worldly pleasures during the daylight hours, from dawn until sunset, in order to focus on spiritual and moral development. In this sense, smoking is seen as a violation of the spirit of fasting because it involves indulging in a physical pleasure and harming the body.

It is important to note that smoking is harmful to health, and Islamic teachings emphasize the importance of taking care of one's body and avoiding activities that harm it. Smoking is associated with a number of health problems, including respiratory problems, heart disease, and cancer, among others.

In conclusion, smoking before Ramadan, but not during the fasting hours, does not invalidate the fast. However, smoking is considered a violation of the spirit of fasting and is discouraged in Islamic teachings, which emphasize the importance of taking care of one's body and avoiding activities that harm it. It is important for individuals to prioritize their health and well-being during Ramadan and throughout the year by avoiding harmful habits and practices.